# What role does the /etc/sysconfig/httpd config file have in the configuration of Apache server?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

My linux distribution has a file /etc/sysconfig/httpd that appears to be related to the configuration of Apache server

Can anyone explain what role this plays in the configuration and why it differs from the role the standard httpd.conf configuration file has - why are there two configuration files?

Answer (score 3):

This is distribution dependent.  I have CentOS (a clone of RedHat advanced server) and i have this file.

When you start your machine, the `init` process looks at a bunch of scripts to see what to start.  One may be `httpd` (you can configure apache to start or not with `chkconfig`).  If you look at your `/etc/init.d/httpd` script, you can see that it checks for `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` and if so sources it (as if it was a part of the current script).  So now any variable definitions in `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` get applied for the rest of the script.

The examples you see in the file are to set `HTTPD`, which is a variable set to the executable name.  In my distro, by default you use the old prefork module, but you can set to use the multithreaded `/usr/sbin/httpd.worker` here if you like.  You can also set OPTIONS, which are command line options given to `httpd` (a.k.a. `$HTTPD`).  There really isn't anything else you can set (you can ignore `HTTPD_LANG`, if you don't know if you need it, you don't need it)

So, if you want the multithreaded server, set `HTTPD=/usr/sbin/httpd.worker`.  This probably won't break anything in the default apache, though some add-ons that you add may (but unlikely) break under multithreaded apache.

Comment: I am using CentOS 7, and httpd is controlled by systemd, so there is no `/etc/init.d/httpd` file. Instead it uses `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/httpd.service`, which has the line `EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/httpd`

Comment: @arthurHebert-Ryan as you know RH7 (and therefore centos7) is EOL.  Sadly RedHat has been trying to Nerf all downstream (Oracle, Centos, Alma, Rocky) for some time and is throwing FUD out there.

Answer (score 2):

This page http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DistrosDefaultLayout says "There is an extra config file in /etc/sysconfig/httpd which can be used to change to the worker mpm /usr/sbin/httpd.worker."